# Create CLOS classes from json-schema?

Tags: json, common-lisp, clos

I'm working on a project that involves a lot of serialisation and deserialisation between Common Lisp and JSON. So far, I've avoided having to duplicate a massive json schema on the lisp side by using alist representations created by the user and only serialising what's needed with [yason](https://phmarek.github.io/yason/)

However, this is becoming tedious and error-prone as the json class hierarchy becomes more deeply nested and it looks increasingly desirable to duplicate the json schema  fully in CLOS. A look around turned up a WIP, [json-schema2](https://gitlab.com/Gnuxie/json-schema2/), but it is far from complete and undocumented.

Is anyone aware of any other libraries for this, or have any experience in converting a json schema into a CLOS class hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Library [Herodotus](https://github.com/HenryS1/herodotus) might solve the problem partially.

You need to define the [CLOS classes](https://github.com/HenryS1/herodotus#basic-usage) manually or you might be able to use YASON's hashtable generated from the JSON to create the classes.